# Nearest Neighbor Distances for a 2D Grid in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested, nearest-neighbor

I have a data set of discrete points over a 2D grid with dimensions of 4x4, each have a given x and y coordinate such as:

```
x_coord, y_coord
0.5     2.1
0.8     3.2
3.3     1.1
2.8     0.6
1.9     1.0
```

I want to step through each grid point to find the distance to the third nearest neighbor.  So I want to know the **distance** to the third nearest neighbor for the following coordinates:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
[0,2]
[0,3]
[1,0]
[1,1]
[1,2]
[1,3]
[2,0]
[2,1]
[2,2]
[2,3]
[3,0]
[3,1]
[3,2]
[3,3]
```

I think that my trouble is coming from how to step through a grid and do the calculation for the distance to the nearest neighbor.  I am just learning python so my experience with nesting for loops is very limited, but my guess is that's what I need here.

So far I have

```
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np

x=[0.5,0.8,3.3,2.8,1.9]
y=[2.1,3.2,1.1,0.6,1.0]

myarray = np.array([x,y])
myarray_trans = np.transpose(myarray)
myarray_trans

nbrs = NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=3, algorithm='ball_tree').fit(myarray_trans)
distances, indices = nbrs.kneighbors(myarray_trans)
```

Now using this as my training set I need to step through the full grid to find the distance to the third nearest neighbor from the discrete list.  I have tried this:

```
for i in range(0,4):
   for j in range(0,4):
      distances2[i,j], indices[i,j] = nbrs.kneighbors([i,j])
```

I get an error that says "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead: array=[0 0]

I will have to do this on a bigger data set with a grid of something more like the size of 500 x 500 so this is an example.

Comment: Hey, you better give use the stack when you bump on an error, so we can see which call fail rather than guessing from what you say.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see on https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html, `nbrs.kneighbors` expect a list of list as input. This is precisely what the error is telling you.

In python `nbrs.kneighbors([i,j])` evaluate to a list such as [3,8], which is a simple list and not a multidimensional array